# How to horizontally center two divs so they are stacked on top of each other?

Tags: html, center

I apologize, this seems like such a newbie question, but I cannot get my divs aligned for the life of me.

I have two divs inside a parent. How do I horizontally center (in relation to the page) two divs but instead of being side by side, I want them to be stacked--one on top of the other.

Here is a little chunk of sample code:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="above">I belong above!</div>
    <div id="below">I belong below!</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add some css.  For example:

```
<style>
#container {
    width: 600px;
}
#above, #below {
    width: 400px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
</style>
```

Add this in the `<head>` tag.